# Ubuntu 17.10 - VGA and HDMI monitors

Tags: nvidia, xubuntu, 17.10, intel-graphics

1, There is a computer for deep learning as below:

- CPU Core i5-7600
- 240GB hard drive (SSD)
- 8GB RAM (DDR4)
- GeForce GTX 1060 6GB

2, In this machine I've installed:

- Ubuntu 17.10 "Artful Aardvark" 58MB
- Xubuntu Minimal

Everything works well.

3, Regarding monitor, I have:

- a 24 inch Dell monitor that can be used with HDMI and VGA
- a 18.5 inch AOC monitor that can be used with VGA only

Both are fine. However at the same time, I only use one of them.

The drivers for nvidia graphic device are already after installing. I can choose between Nouveau and Nvidia's version. Everything works well.

4, Then I installed CUDA and cuDNN to support TensorFlow and similar tools. The problem started here.

**Phenomena**:

- Dell monitor via HDMI is still work as normal, doesn't work via VGA port.
- AOC monitor no longer work. If I plug this monitor into, and restart the system, it will boot as normal except of the screen is pending at Xubuntu logo, could not get past the welcome screen.
- I can access it from another computer via SSH. However, restarting X-Server doesn't help.
- It works if at first I plug Dell monitor via HDMI, restart computer to get into Xubuntu desktop, then remove Dell monitor to replace it with Dell monitor via VGA.
- With this workaround, it works. But the screen will be hung up once I try to lock it (with Ctrl + Alt + Del for example). Then I found that Screensaver is the solution for this issue. Keep the screensaver running and I can get back to desktop anytime.

Sorry for so long description but I feel the problem is quite odd. My question is, how I can get the VGA based monitor works as normal without fooling the computer by using a HDMI based device?

Thank you for any suggestion.